# Publish postgis raster based on column value in geoserver

Tags: raster, geoserver, query, parameters

I have a postgis raster table with the following columns:
rid, rast, year, plant

I created a wms layer in geoserver pointing to the table and successfully serve out the raster when the table only has one raster in it (one plant). The url used to do this looks like so:

```
http://<myserver>/geoserver/sde/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sde:prism_spring_index&styles=&bbox=-125.0,24.2,-66.9,49.9166666666687&width=768&height=339&srs=EPSG:4269&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true
```

The problem is I added a second raster to the table for a different plant. How can I set things up so that I can pass a param in the url to geoserver to specify a "plant=lilac" parameter so that the appropriate raster is displayed?

I tried using (CQL_FILTER) like this but it doesn't seem to work

```
http://<myserver>/geoserver/sde/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sde:prism_spring_index&CQL_FILTER=plant=%27lilac%27&styles=&bbox=-125.0,24.2,-66.9,49.9166666666687&width=768&height=339&srs=EPSG:4269&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true
```

I'm pretty new to geoserver, so I'm not sure if I need to define two layers pointing to the same postgis table to get this working or if I just need one layer. Either way, how do the layers know how to specify which raster to pull from a table?

Here's a screenshot showing how CQL is disabled when I preview the layer. Even though you only see one US raster, there are multiple US rasters in the table that the layer points to and I'm not sure how it is picking which one to show. Is there a way to enable the CQL filter? I'm using imagemosaicJDBC.

[image: CQL disabled screenshot]

Comment: can you say why "it doesn't seem to work"? You might want to look at views (http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.5/user/data/database/sqlview.html)

Comment: @iant It doesn't seem to work means that the served raster is an arbitrary composite of tiles from all available rasters stored in the postgis table and the CQL_FILTER has no effect.

Comment: @iant Thanks for the link. As I tried to follow it I noticed that instead of "Configure new SQL view" my layer page only has the option "Configure new Coverage view". I believe this is because I have an Image Mosaic JDBC data store, not a straight up postgis datastore. I was under the impression that since I'm storing rasters in the postigs db, this is the correct datastore to use. Maybe I'm wrong about this since I want geoserver to query the table to display a specific raster?